# How do i loop through these objects inside an array using forEach?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an array and inside i have a group of objects and how would i loop through them and to make a check for which one of the objects have a status as true?

```
menuItems: [
  {
    text1: 'Apple',
    status: false,
    subItems: []
  },
  {
    text2: 'Orange',
    status: false,
    subItems: []
  },
  {
   text3: 'Banana',
    status: true,
    subItems: []
  }
]
```

I tried something like this:-

```
if(menuItems.forEach(active) === 'false') {
then('do something!!!')
}
```

Comment: i would use filter if i was you. `let trueItems = menuItems.filter(item => item.status);` If you wanted to take it one step further, follow with map. `trueItems.map( item => processForTrueItem(item) );`

Comment: Is this some assignment that requires you to use `forEach`?  It's possible to do, so but `forEach` may not be the best tool for the job.

Comment: Is there guaranteed to be just one item with `status` of `true`, or could there be several?

Comment: @Scott yeah there could be several, this is just a short example.

Comment: Would you also have to find the `true` statuses among any `subItems`?  That would best be handled recursively.

Comment: no need to worry about subItems. I might not even need it. Just threw that in there. but if you want to do a separate answer. sure by all means,

Comment: Just trying to tease out your requirements.  Is `forEach` necessary for any reason?  Or could you use `filter`?

Comment: which ever one you think is the easiest will do.

Comment: @ScottSauyet actually if you could show the filter way, that might work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example:

```js
const menuItems = [
  {
    text: 'Apple',
    status: false,
    subItems: []
  },
  {
    text: 'Orange',
    status: false,
    subItems: []
  },
  {
   text: 'Banana',
    status: true,
    subItems: []
  }
];

menuItems.forEach(menuItem => { if(menuItem.status) { console.log(menuItem.text) } });
```

Read MDN!

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: This was awesome. thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple options. On the top level, you could add an if statement to the function passed to `forEach`:

```
menuItems.forEach((item) => {
  if (item.status) {
    console.log('Do something') // only logs when item.status is true
  }
})
```

Note that your sample code: `menuItems.forEach(active) === 'false')` would not work even after fixing the syntax, because in your sample data `status` is a boolean, and you're trying to compare it to a string with `===`.

Back to the main question though: Instead of having an if statement, you could use the `filter` method to first remove any items that *don't* have a status of true:

```
menuItems.filter(item => item.status).forEach((item) => {
  // The filter function will remove any items where item.status is falsy,
  // leaving only items where status is true.
  console.log('Do something')
})
```

Comment: Thank you. really detailed answer.